# Mockito verify wait and notify

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm wondering if there is a way to use Mockito to verify wait or notifyAll?

```
public class Sample {
    public synchronized void test1() {
        this.notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void test2() {
        if (condition) {
            this.wait()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific test to write?

Comment: Mockito, no. Perhaps you can do it indirectly instead: e.g. have something else wait on an instance of `Sample`; if that something gets notified as a result of calling `test1`, you know that Sample called a notify* method.